# Why didn't Electron's first stage go "There and Back Again"?

Tags: failure, recovery, rocketlab, helicopter, electron

During the "There and Back Again" mission, it [seems to have been caught](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nODVPGHQcc) around the 52:45 mark. Then it also seems like the helicopter dropped it. Was this intentional? If so, why? It seems odd to me to go through the entire complex recovery process and then to drop to the ocean like you could have without the helicopter? Was the entire helicopter being there a test then?

Comment: Helicopters are dynamically unstable, and capturing a load in the air is a hazardous maneuver. If the load is too heavy the forces required to keep the cargo aloft could be outside the performance envelope, which could lead to a loss of control, or require the engines to be run past safety limits. If the cargo starts to swing it could also lead to a loss of control. You cut it loose before it puts you in a non-recoverable situation.

Comment: Okay. And rocket la b never thought to calculate those forces. I doubt that @GdD

Comment: I'm sure they did, and I'm sure they practiced capture a number of times. There's a difference between simulation and the real thing, maybe there was still propellant in the tanks which put it above weight, or the winds aloft were higher than they expected. There are many things to go wrong with that type of maneuver.

Comment: So my question is what went wrong causing them to need to drop it @GdD

Comment: I understood your question just fine @Starshipisgoforlaunch. As I do not have a definite answer I used the comment field to add information which is relevant. It's common practice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was this intentional?

Yes, it was, [as is explained in the same video you linked to](https://youtube.com/live/6nODVPGHQcc?t=5758) [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> ***At his discretion*** the pilot offloaded the stage for a successful splashdown where it is being recovered by our vessel for transport back to our factory.

So, the pilot *intentionally* triggered the quick release on the catch hook.

> If so, why?

[This is explained in the same video you linked to](https://youtube.com/live/6nODVPGHQcc?t=5747) [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> Now, after the catch, ***the helicopter pilot noticed different load characteristics*** than we have experienced in testing. Which of course you *do* expect when testing anything in the field for the first time.

So, the pilot noticed that the load was behaving differently than what they were used to from the tests where they caught the mass simulator.

> It seems odd to me to go through the entire complex recovery process and then to drop to the ocean like you could have without the helicopter?

There is nothing odd about this. One of the fundamental rules of aviation is that the *Pilot-In-Command (PIC)* of an aircraft has ultimate authority over any safety-related aspects. If the pilot feels that in order to guarantee the safety of the crew, it is necessary to drop a multi-million dollar piece of hardware, then they are free to do so.

> Was the entire helicopter being there a test then?

This is explained multiple times in the video you linked to. This was the very first catch attempt in the development program for booster recovery. The program is still under development, and this was the first time Rocket Lab (or anyone else, for that matter) attempted to catch an orbital class booster in mid-air.

Note the word *attempt*, which is prominently used in the description of the video you linked to as well as multiple times during the webcast.